# Show that one of these numbers is a Square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, show that at least one of the following values is a square in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $p$ prime

Those values are:

$a^2 -b^2$, $2(b-a)$, $2(-a-b)$.

I tried multiplying, adding and substracting those values but I can't conclude anything.

**edit:**  I forgot to mention that the numbers must be squares mod $p$

Comment: It seems none of them is necessarily the square of an integer.

Comment: I think the real question concerned quadratic residues modulo some odd prime.

Comment: Well if $b= 3$ and $a=2$ then $a^2  - b^2 = -5$ and $2(b-a)= 2$ and $2(-a-b) =-10$ and none of those are squares.  I'm a bit perplex why it uses $2(-a-b)$ which is negative if $a,b$ are positive.

Comment: @fleablood the question was edited about five minutes after your comment

Comment: @WillJagy the post is still incorrect because none of them are squares.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw By editing to be about *modulo arithemetic mod a prime $p$* it is corrected.  For example my example of $b=3$ and $a=2$ holds for $\mathbb Z_7$ because $a^2-b^2\equiv -5\equiv 2\equiv 9 \equiv 3^2 \pmod 7$.  And for $\mathbb Z_{17}$ then $2(b-a)\equiv 2 \equiv 36 \equiv 6^2 \pmod {17}$ and so on.

Comment: @fleablood Can any prime number be used for p?

Comment: Yes, @Radial Arm Saw, any prime

Comment: Ok.  Does $\mathbb{Z}$ with a subscript always refer to mod?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$a^2-b^2=(b-a)(-a-b)$$

Now, assume $a^2-b^2$ is not a square in $\mathbb Z_p.$

---

More generally, if $u,v,w$ are integers, then at least one of $uv,uw,vw$ is a square modulo $p.$ In your case, $u=b-a, v=-a-b, w=2.$

---

Even more generally, if $xyz$ is a square modulo $p,$ then so is at least one of $x,y,z.$

Comment: Then either $b-a$ or $-a-b$ is not a square

Comment: More importantly, one is a square and the other is not. @JavierVásquez

Comment: @ThomasAndrews not when a=1 and b=4.  In that case $b-a=3$ and $-a-b=-5$.  Neither of those are squares.

Comment: Which $p$ are you using, @RadialArmSaw ?

Comment: I don’t understand.  I thought a “square” is a number that has a square root which is a whole number.

Comment: No, this is about squares modulo a prime $p.$ For example, when $p=7,$ $-5\equiv 3^2\pmod 7.$ @RadialArmSaw

Comment: In your general case, when $p=7$ and $u,v,w=1,2,3$ is such a counter example.

Comment: No, $uv=2\equiv 3^2\pmod 7.$ @W.Wongcharoenbhorn

Comment: "More generally, if u,v,w are integers, then at least one of uv,uw,vw is a square modulo p"  That's a heck of a claim isn't it.  Is that supposed to be an known result.

Comment: Oh, great, my bad. What an interesting problem.

Comment: @fleablood It follows simply from the fact that the product of three non-squares, modulo $p$ is not a square modulo $p.$ Since $(uv)(uw)(vw)=(uvw)^2$ is a square, one of the three must be a square.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your comments. Let $p$ odd. Since $x\mapsto x^2$ induces a multiplicative endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, and its image is the subgroup $F$ of square numbers, ir follows that the index $[\mathbb{Z}_p^* : F] =2$. Hence if $x,y,z$ are nonsquares in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$,

$$(xF)(yF)(zF) = zF$$

Hence the product of three nonsquares is a nonsquare and we have proved the Thomas assertion